# drupal bread crumb view to show only Home > Search

Tags: drupal, breadcrumbs

I just added search to my drupal theme

and when it go to the search page my bread crumb shows

home > Search > Content > Search

is there a way to make it  just

Home > Search

Thanks
Terry

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module to work that out.